# AdonisJs configure Indicative

Tags: adonis.js

I need to remove all body attributes that is not on the rules of my Validator, Adonis uses the Indicative lib to validate the data and on its configuration I can use the `removeAdditional` to remove the attributes. The problem is how do I configure the Indicative through the Adonis Validator ? I have tried something similar to the way we configure a new custom rules but I had no success

```
const Validator = use('Validator'); 
Validator.configure({ removeAdditional: true });
```

I saw that [here](https://github.com/adonisjs/validator/blob/ed1bbeabe1bdcb53ce9d73a4155391c9809ec7fb/providers/ValidatorProvider.ts#L31) the `validator.configure` is set by getting the validator config from the `app.js` file, but even adding `validator: { removeAdditional: true }` I had no success